# A strange Oracle SQL with from 3 tables but only left join 2 in where clause?

Tags: mysql, oracle, left-join

I constantly see "from" 2 tables and "join" 2 tables examples. That's why when I see following Oracle SQL statement, I feel strange:

```
select a.oid, m.acct, p.cdate
from a, p, m
where a.oid = p.oid(+) and a.uid = m.uid
```

1. What does it actually happen in DBMS?
2. What's the equivalent MySQL syntax?
3. Is **JOIN** just another way to express some conditions in where clause?
   e.g. *a left join b on a.id=b.id* is actually only another way
   to express *a.id = b.id or a.id not in (select b.id from b)* in
   where clause

Comment: Actually, it does have JOIN condition for all 3 table. The first condition "a.oid = p.oid(+)" is LEFT JOIN between *a* and *p*, and the second condition "a.uid = m.uid" is INNER JOIN between *a* and *m*

Comment: Can you share all 3 tables structure and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
select a.oid, m.acct, p.cdate
from a left outer join p on (a.oid = p.oid)
inner join m on (a.uid = m.uid)
```

Query you posted is written in old syntax but does exactly the same as select above. Having simpler example:

```
select * from a, b where a.id = b.id;
```

is also equivalent to:

```
select * from a inner join b on (a.id = b.id);
```

Both queries should be processed same way by optimizer. Also join order is determined by optimizer. So getting back to original example optimizer will define if first apply `inner join` and then `left join` or opposite.